# How can I fix 'non_constant_list_element' error in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making an login page with flutter.

In the app, I get the information from user by using TextFormField, so I defined my custom class, 'CustomTextFormFiled', and it gets 3 parameter. The title of the formfield is first one, second one is hintText, and final one is controller.

After setting is finished, i found a error, it says 'The values in a const list literal must be constant. Try removing the keyword 'const' from the list literal.'

I tried changing definition type from final to const, but it not worked. How can i fix it?

Thank you for concerning me.
[image]

This is how controllers are defined,

[image]
and this one shows the way how i gave parameters

[image]

And this one is my custom text formfield class.
enter code here

Comment: Please avoid posting images instead of codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `CustomTextFieldController`, instead of `dynamic controller`  you can declare it `TextEditingController controller`.

And also `_username, id` declare as follows:

```
TextEditingController _userName = TextEditingController;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I wrote const feature on the code that is not shown in the picture.

`child: ListView(children: const [
SizedBox(height: xlarge_gap),
Logo("Register"),

```
          CustomTextFormField(`
```

const aftert children was the reason of the problem.
Thank you.